# Check if string constant exists in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How do I check whether a string constant is defined in Objective-C?

Using `UIViewControllerShowDetailTargetDidChangeNotification` on iOS 7 causes a crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (&UIViewControllerShowDetailTargetDidChangeNotification) {
    // ... safe to use ...
}
```